# Yodlee executeUserSearchRequest keeps returning the first 500 transactions

Tags: yodlee

I did the following way to get all the transactions back, but i kept getting back the first 500 transactions all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This API doesn't do return the same transactions until you are passing the input parameters correctly.Here is what I would suggest you.

1. Use getUserTransactions API in tandem with executeUserSearchRequest this will have faster response, as it would be using the searchIdentifier returned by executeUserSearchRequest.
2. I'd request you to show your actual code instead of the screenshot of the documentation.

As that will help to identify what/where exactly the issue is.